# Derivative on parametric function. (Check my answer)

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

> Let $x=t^2$ and $y=\sin 2t$. Determine $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.

I have tried as below. Is this right or wrong answer?

\begin{align*}
  \dfrac{dy}{dx}&= \dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\dfrac{2\cos 2t}{2t}=
  \dfrac{\cos 2t}{t}.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 \dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2}&= \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right) = \dfrac{dy'}{dx} = 
 \dfrac{\dfrac{dy'}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{-t \sin 2t-\cos 2t}{t^2}}{2t}=\dfrac{-t \sin 2t-\cos 2t}{2t^3}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}= \dfrac{\dfrac{-(2)t \sin 2t-\cos 2t}{t^2}}{2t}=\dfrac{-(2)t \sin 2t-\cos 2t}{2t^3}.$$
Mind (2) in above which you have missed.